# VirtualBox skips creating host only network #2 and directly creates #3

Tags: virtualbox, network-adapter

My problem is not interrupting my work, yet I can't understand the reason for this behavior:

I am trying to create a new host-only adapter using VirtualBox.
When I do so using the Host Network Manager, adapter #3 is created even though adapter #2 doesn't exist. I checked the device manager and it doesn't show up there as well.

I'll mention that this didn't happen on a "clean" machine, but I had a few VM's installed before, Docker, etc. So my guess is this is the result of some "leftovers".

How can I fix this?